# tensorflow select list of indices along dimension

Tags: tensorflow

In order to select a list of columns in a matrix I am doing the following:

```
sel = tf.concat([tf.slice(mat, [0, i], [-1, 1]) for i in list_columns],
                axis=1)
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.gather` will be more efficient and concise. Let `axis=1`, then you can select columns in specified indices.

```py
mat = tf.constant(np.arange(12).reshape(2,6))
#[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
# [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]]
list_columns = [0,2,4]

res = tf.gather(mat, [0,2,4], axis=1)
#[[ 0,  2,  4],
# [ 6,  8, 10]]
```